# Agregar nombre de una propiedad de un objeto, como valor de una propiedad en otro objeto Javascript

Tags: javascript, array, typescript, bucles, objeto

tengo un problema, estoy consumiendo una api pero esta api, me trae los datos de una manera que no necesito, estoy iterando esa lista de objetos para crear un objeto personalizado que me facilite el trabajo, el problema es que una propiedad de este nuevo objeto tiene como valor el nombre de una propiedad del api que estoy consumiendo,

```
  //Esta es la lista de objetos que consumo del api 
            let a = [
              {"horario":"07:30 - 09:30","lunes":{"id":11,"description":"Actividades de Docencia - DOC.Importición de clases","estado":"aprobado"},"martes":null,"miercoles":null,"jueves":null,"viernes":null,"sabado":null,"domingo":null,"nrc":"3903","periodo":null},
              {"horario":"08:30 - 10:20","lunes":null,"martes":null,"miercoles":null,"jueves":null,"viernes":null,"sabado":{"id":21,"description":"OTROS (Comisión, Becas,etc) - Otros","estado":"aprobado"},"domingo":null,"nrc":null,"periodo":null},
              {"horario":"17:15 - 19:15","lunes":null,"martes":{"id":13,"description":"Actividades de Docencia - DOC.Importición de clases","estado":"aprobado"},"miercoles":null,"jueves":{"id":14,"description":"Actividades de Docencia - DOC.Importición de clases","estado":"aprobado"},"viernes":null,"sabado":null,"domingo":null,"nrc":"3878","periodo":null},
              {"horario":"07:15 - 09:15","lunes":null,"martes":null,"miercoles":{"id":9,"description":"Actividades de Docencia - DOC.Importición de clases","estado":"aprobado"},"jueves":null,"viernes":{"id":10,"description":"Actividades de Docencia - DOC.Importición de clases","estado":"aprobado"},"sabado":null,"domingo":null,"nrc":"3903","periodo":null},
              {"horario":"09:30 - 11:30","lunes":null,"martes":{"id":12,"description":"Actividades de Docencia - DOC.Importición de clases","estado":"aprobado"},"miercoles":null,"jueves":null,"viernes":null,"sabado":null,"domingo":null,"nrc":"3903","periodo":null}
            ]; 
   
         //en esta funcion elimino todas las propiedades nulas de la lista de objetos
            const result = a.map((obj) => Object.fromEntries(Object.entries(obj).filter(([k, v]) => v !== null)));
        
          //Ejemplo del primer objeto sin propiedades nulas
          [{'horario':'07:30 - 09:30','lunes':{'id':11,'description':'Actividades de Docencia - DOC.Importición de clases','estado':'aprobado'},'nrc':'3903'}];

        //Itero la lista de Objetos para crear mi objeto personalizado
            for(let as of result){
                var res = as.horario.split("-");
            
             //Agrego los valores al objeto personalizado
            arreglo.push(
              {
                dia: ??????????? //No sé como poner el nombre dinamicamente de la propiedad en este caso para el primer objeto de la lista deberia ser lunes
                horaInicio:res[0].trim(),
                horaFin: res[1].trim(),
              }
            )
            }
            
            console.log("arreglo: " + JSON.stringify(arreglo));
```

Me podrian ayudar como solucionar mi problema o alguna recomendacion.
Muchas Gracias

[CODIGO EN STACBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-acghth?file=index.js)

Comment: Supongo que lo mejor seria usar `dia: Object.keys(as)[1]` pero claro, después tendrás que lidiar con otros casos con más dias o vete a saber, así que mejor analiza bien como lo harás para filtrar bien ese dato y que efectivamente esa key se corresponda con un dia y no sea **horario**, **nrc** o **periodo** por los motivos que sea

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mi recomendación es que en crees un ciclo `for` anidado:

```
for (let index = 0; index < Object.keys(as).length; index++) {
    as.days = []
    const propName = Object.keys(as)[index];
    if(
      propName === "lunes" || 
      propName === "martes" || 
      propName === "miercoles" || 
      propName === "jueves" || 
      propName === "viernes" || 
      propName === "sabado" || 
      propName === "domingo" 
    ) {
      as.days.push({
        [propName]: as[propName]
      })
    }
    arreglo.push({
      dia: as.days,
      horaInicio: res[0].trim(),
      horaFin: res[1].trim(),
    });
  }
```

Se repetirá por la cantidad de veces que tenga de largo el objeto `as` gracias al `Object.keys(as).length`.

Dentro de él, inicializas la nueva propiedad `as.days` como un array vacío.

Luego consigue el nombre de cada propiedad del objeto `as` mediante el   `const propName = Object.keys(as)[index]`.

Mediante un `if` preguntas si el nombre de esa propiedad coincide con algún día de la semana.

```
if(
      propName === "lunes" || 
      propName === "martes" || 
      propName === "miercoles" || 
      propName === "jueves" || 
      propName === "viernes" || 
      propName === "sabado" || 
      propName === "domingo" 
    ) { ...
```

Y en caso afirmativo, le haces un push al nuevo array que creaste con un nuevo objeto cuya propiedad será dinámica: `[propName]: ...` , y que dentro tendrá el valor de la propiedad del objeto original: `as[propName]`.

Una vez obtenido un array con todos los días de la semana que puede o no tener cada objeto `as`, finalmente puedes ponerlo dentro de la propiedad `dia` de tu array llamado `arreglo`:

```
 arreglo.push({
      dia: as.days,
      horaInicio: res[0].trim(),
      horaFin: res[1].trim(),
    });
```

Te dejo el [código en STACBLITZ](https://stackblitz.com/edit/js-ze1cte?file=index.js) así lo miras funcionando.

**PD:** Toda esta lógica contempla la posibilidad de que la propiedad `dia` tenga más de un día de la semana dentro. Si siempre va a tener un solo día nada más, puedes reciclar la lógica y usar solo un objeto con el día en vez de un array de días.

Comment: Muchas Gracias, me sirvio de mucho